# How to get date input in UIDateTimePicker in react-native-ui-lib

Tags: reactjs, react-native

`React-native-ui-lib` provide a componnent called  `UIDateTimePicker` to make a date or time picker, but how can we get date **we selected**? For example if i choose a date, then it show in console,for example? It only show on `<UIDateTimePicker>` component

Please help, thank a lots

Comment: Did you try the "onChange" prop. With it you can, for example, save the date value with useState hook.

Comment: I tried but no luck :( , it seen like onChange do not do anything